# CSS - Avoid black area in video 1:1

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, video.js

I have a squared video (scale 1:1) and I want to place it in the middle of the screen.

My first and biggest problem is that with the tag `<video>` the player insert 2 black area on both sides. How can I avoid this thing?

[image]

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: red;">
        <video>
        <source src="~/Content/video/FreeBirdConstruction.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

The div that contains it is squared (400px x 400px) so why doesn't the video fill it?
I also tried to use VideoJS but it didn't solve my problem.

Secondo question.
If I try to move the div in the middle of the screen, for example in this way:

```
position: absolute; /*it can be fixed too*/
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
```

at first the div appears in the middle of the screen, but immediatly disappear.

Could you pls help me to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the height and width of the video within the video tag:

```
<div style="background-color: red;">
    <video width="400" height="400">
        <source src="~/Content/video/FreeBirdConstruction.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

I would think that would force it to stay square.

To center your div, it must be getting confused. You gave it a specific width/height, but then also want the bounding edges of the div to touch all corners of your screen. Try something like this (and remove the css you gave it (left, right, top, etc.):

```
div{
    display:inline-block; /*this will keep the div the size of it's contents*/
    margin:auto; /*this should give it equal margins on all sides, thus centering*/
}
```

Comment: nothing changed with your edits... 
the video is just vertically centered in the div.

Comment: If you can provide a jfiddle with your code displaying how you see it that would be helpful :)